# How to use databases within the python unittest framework?

Tags: unit-tests, python, database

I have a bunch of unittests written in `python` in which messages (text) of any kind is used. Instead of 'hardcoding' the text examples used for the tests I would like to use a database of some kind (simple text file, pickle file) which contains such test examples, and which can be extended either manually or automatically very easily.

Is there a dedicated framework/module available, or do I do this simply on my own and create a simple text file? Maybe there are some best practices available I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

Alex,

You might want to look at some of the answers to this question: [What are some good approaches to separating test data from test scripts?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6678/what-are-some-good-approaches-to-separating-test-data-from-test-scripts)

It's not specifically aimed at unit tests, but the general principle is similar. If your unit test framework doesn't support a data source attribute or declaration, you could design your own method of using external data sources.